# Entity framework save changes

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Is there a point to save changes after a read only action? The entities are loaded to cache, but nothing changes, should save changes be called before dispose?

Comment: What's the purpose of saving something if no changes were made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [doc (`DbContext.SaveChanges`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database.

No there is no point in calling `SaveChanges` if you have not made any changes on your context.

You can read more about this in detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

> An entity can be in one of five states as defined by the EntityState enumeration. These states are:
>
> - Added: the entity is being tracked by the context but does not yet exist in  the database
> - Unchanged: the entity is being tracked by the context and exists in the database, and its property values have not changed from the values in the database
> - Modified: the entity is being tracked by the context and exists in the database, and some or all of its property values have been modified
> - Deleted: the entity is being tracked by the context and exists in the database, but has been marked for deletion from the database the next time SaveChanges is called
> - Detached: the entity is not being tracked by the context
>
> SaveChanges does different things for entities in different states:
>
> - Unchanged entities are not touched by SaveChanges. Updates are not sent to the database for entities in the Unchanged state.
> - Added entities are inserted into the database and then become Unchanged when SaveChanges returns.
> - Modified entities are updated in the database and then become Unchanged when SaveChanges returns.
> - Deleted entities are deleted from the database and are then detached from the context.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `SaveChanges()` unless you do:

1. `Add`
2. `Update`
3. `Delete`