# entity framework savechanges not Working MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i am  saving data through Model. SaveChanges not saving new record in database.
and not throwing any exception. kindly help anyone to get me out this situation.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAmbulanceLocation1(Ambulance_Position AMmodel)
{

    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;


        //  var m = db.Ambulance_Position.FirstOrDefault(x => x.A_unique_ID == AMmodel.A_unique_ID);
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AMmodel.Date_Time = System.DateTime.Now;
                db.Ambulance_Position.Add(AMmodel);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {

        }

        return Json("saved", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: In your code snippet, you are doing nothing with the caught exception so you can't know if there is any exception.

Comment: Something like `Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())` could help

Comment: Is your ModelState actually valid?

Comment: Tell me have you set what is the primary key for ambulance_Position table in the model?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier id is Primary key and it is auto increment

Comment: yes, but have you specified that in the model, you created in the entity framework model? if id is the primarykey have you put the [Key] attribute over it?

Comment: another posibility is that AMmodel.id  is 0 and therefore not updating anything

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier no need to put [Key] attribute It is working for other model same but for this model not saving change

Comment: @umersafeer sometimes entityframework cant identify what is the primarykey. so we put the [Key] attribute

Comment: and it does not  go to  exception when  i debug code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172654/discussion-between-sujit-warrier-and-umer-safeer).

Comment: Please share ambulance_position class and database value types.So what is the exception details?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest making changes to your ActionMethod as shown below; basis [this accepted Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403667/entity-framework-save-changes).

*Note that this example is not tested though; and I might be wrong...*

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAmbulanceLocation1(Ambulance_Position AMmodel)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Ambulance_Position ambulance_position = new Ambulance_Position();
        ambulance_position = AMmodel;

        //  var m = db.Ambulance_Position.FirstOrDefault(x => x.A_unique_ID == AMmodel.A_unique_ID);
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //AMmodel.Date_Time = System.DateTime.Now;
                ambulance_position.Date_Time = System.DateTime.Now;
                db.Ambulance_Position.Add(ambulance_position);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return Json("saved", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```